# MySQL 1064 syntax error cant find error

Tags: mysql, sql

can someone please help me with this sql query. it gives me a 1064 error suggesting I have a syntax error in my query. I've looked for the error over 2 hours now and getting frustrated now.

```
SELECT 
 SUM(IF( (`date` >= DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) AND (`date` < DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 5 MONTH)), earnings, 0)) AS Rev5,
 SUM(IF( (`date` >= DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 5 MONTH)) AND (`date` < DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 4 MONTH)), earnings, 0)) AS Rev4,
 SUM(IF( (`date` >= DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 4 MONTH)) AND (`date` < DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)), earnings, 0)) AS Rev3,
 SUM(IF( (`date` >= DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) AND (`date` < DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), earnings, 0)) AS Rev2,
 SUM(IF( (`date` >= DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) AND (`date` < DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), earnings, 0)) AS Rev1,
 SUM(IF( (`date` >= DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND (`date` < ?), earnings, 0)) AS Rev0
FROM
 hat_adsense_stats
GROUP BY 
 domain
ORDER BY
 domain
```

thanks here is the error:

> Error Code: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND (`date` < ?), earnings, 0)) as Rev0
>   FROM
>    hat_adsens' at line 2

Comment: Plz make the SQL syntax readable by proper formatting it...

Comment: Are you using PDO, mysqli, or some other syntax to bind the values to your parameters? If so, are you binding the correct parameter type?

Comment: @SantoshGhimire: and please make your comments readable by not using leet speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `parameter place holders` on your query, which do not work on pure sql. The only time `?` works is when you create a `Dynamic SQL`.

If you are working with query that is not a `Dynamic SQL`, you should provide a value for that.

On example to remove the syntax error on the statement is to create a `user variable`, eg

```
SET @date = CURDATE();
SELECT 
 SUM(IF( (`date` >= DATE_SUB(@date, INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) AND (`date` < DATE_SUB(@date, INTERVAL 5 MONTH)), earnings, 0)) AS Rev5,
 SUM(IF( (`date` >= DATE_SUB(@date, INTERVAL 5 MONTH)) ........
```

Comment: thanks that is the problem! :) i got the original code from a friend and tested it in normal sql-yog. I use it in PHP and MySQL PDO. when working in the code environment it works 100%.

Comment: when you are using `PDO`, just leave the `?` as the values should be  parameterized.